# Can someone explain RemoteViews GC behavior?

Tags: android, memory, garbage-collection

I have a download task that reports progress to a notification periodically. For awhile I was using one RemoveView private member to update each time.

For example:

```
private RemoteViews mRemoteView;
protected void onCreate(){
    mRemoteView = new RemoteViews( getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_layout )
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_icon, R.drawable.downloads);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, "Downloading A File " + (int)( (double)progress/(double)max * 100 ) + "%");
    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.mProgress, max, progress, false);

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.mProgress, max, progress, false);
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}
```

However, I found that the GC was constantly clearing out space and slowing that app down to a crawl for a long time. I tried then creating a new RemoteViews each time i updated, and that works. I'm wondering why this is. I found a link [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a90e12579c0beee3?pli=1) that was kind of helpful, but I'm looking for more information.

Here's the code that works:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_icon, R.drawable.downloads);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, "Downloading A File " + (int)( (double)progress/(double)max * 100 ) + "%");
        contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.mProgress, max, progress, false);

        notification.contentView = contentView;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link that you provided explains it:

RemoteViews is used for creating a View in a remote process. Actually it's not a View, but just a set of commands that get queued. Then this queue is serialized, sent to a remote process, deserialized and then this set of actions is executed. The result is a fully build View in a remote process.

As link explains it: every time you call a method on RemoteViews, an actions is added to it's queue. Unfortunately there is no way to clear the queue, so it keeps on growing, until you get OOM exception.

Now, queue is internally backed by an array (as are all Collections). When queue fills it's internal array it needs to create a new bigger one and copy all old data. GC then clears the old array. Since RemoteViews internal queue is constantly growing, new arrays are created and GC is constantly clearing old arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The queue does get removed as time goes by though correct? So if my onProgressUpdate() got called every 1 hour ( just using a long example ) then there should be no problem? In my example it was getting updated very frequently so I can see why this queue would be a problem.

Comment: Yes with slow usage the problem would be less severe - the GC would be able to cope with the job. But this does not change the fact that queue inside RemoteViews newer gets cleared. RemoteViews are just a set of commands to build a View. If you keep adding commands to it than building a View on remote side would also take longer time.